# How to persist modified/loaded properties in a pom?

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I use different maven plugins to resolve properties from a file (properties-maven-plugin) and manipulate them during the life-cycle (gmaven-plugin).

In the end (at deploy) I would like to have all those properties visible in the output pom, but so far I haven't found out how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the maven-help-plugin would help you ?

```
mvn help:effective-pom
```

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/usage.html

You would see the effective pom but without any comments, so you won't be able to persist it.

As far as I know, what you require does not exist.